# Left Join with duplicate keys in the right table

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying merging 2 tables as follow

```
 SELECT * FROM T1 
 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.EMPnum = T2.EMPnum
```

The above works well but I need the joining to use only **the first appearance** of the common key `EMPnum` record in table T2 so that the query returns **exactly** the same number of rows as T1

Thanks Avi

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Can you change the * to a specific list of fields. e.g. T1.somefield, T1.someotherfield etc...

Comment: What is the "first appearance"? Just any one of the matching rows? Or is there some specific order you want considered?

Answer (score 1):

SQL tables are inherently unordered, so there is no such thing as a "first" key.  In most databases, you can do something like this:

```
with t2 as (
      select t2.*, row_number() over (partition by EMPnum order by id) as seqnum
      from t2
     )
select *
from t1 left join
     t2
     on t1.EMPnum = t2.EMPnum and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Here `id` is just any column that specifies the ordering.  If none exist, you can use `EMPnum` to get an arbitrary row.